# Near immutable, thread safe Builder

Tags: java, design-patterns, thread-safety, immutability

I'm writing a torrent streaming client. The plan is to wrap WebTorrent-cli and provide a Java interface to observe download state, cancel or pause downloads etc.

Anyways, I came up with the following `DownloadManagerImpl`. I want the instances to this class be immutable, strictly enough that they remain thread safe if accessed from multiple threads. I'm using the builder pattern to create instances of `DownloadManagerImpl` as more fields can be added in the future. I would like to avoid any repetitions of fields. Really sorry for posting the partly documented (and yet unfinished:)) code, but here it is:

```
package hyena.dmanager;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor;
import org.apache.commons.exec.Executor;

import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

/**
 * Default implementation for DownloadManager.
 *
 * @author Devashish Jaiswal
 * @see hyena.dmanager.DownloadManager
 */
public final class DownloadManagerImpl implements DownloadManager {
    private transient Executor exec;

    /**
     * Absolute path of the directory where files will be saved,
     * excluding the file name.
     */
    @SerializedName(JsonKey.SAVE_LOCATION)
    private Path mSaveTo;

    /** Magnet URL of the torrent. */
    @SerializedName(JsonKey.MAGNET_URL)
    private String mMagnetUrl;

    /**
     * Absolute path to vlc media player's install location. User
     * assistance might be required for this field.
     */
    @SerializedName(JsonKey.VLC_PATH)
    private Path mVlcPath;

    /**
     * WebTorrent has this tendency to hang in-between downloads if
     * the network is slow. On these situations, we kill this instance
     * of the downloader, save download state and compose a new task that
     * loads the state and resumes download.
     */
    @SerializedName(JsonKey.RESUME_TIMEOUT)
    private int mResumeAfterInactiveSeconds;

    /**
     * The index of the file to be downloaded in a multi-file torrent.
     * Set it to -ve if all files have to be downloaded, or if torrent
     * contains only a single file.
     */
    @SerializedName(JsonKey.FILE_INDEX)
    private int mFileIndex;

    private DownloadManagerImpl(){}

    @Override
    public void start() {

    }

    @Override
    public ProgressState getProgressState() {
        return null;
    }

    public String exportStateJson () {
        return new Gson().toJson(this);
    }


    private class JsonKey {
        static final String MAGNET_URL = "magent_url";
        static final String RESUME_TIMEOUT = "inactivity_resume_timeout";
        static final String SAVE_LOCATION = "save_location";
        static final String VLC_PATH = "vlc_path";
        static final String FILE_INDEX = "file_index";
    }

    public static class Builder {
        private boolean isCompositionComplete;
        private final DownloadManagerImpl mManager;

        public Builder () {
            isCompositionComplete = false;
            mManager = new DownloadManagerImpl();
            mManager.exec = new DefaultExecutor();
        }

        private synchronized boolean canModify() {
            if (isCompositionComplete) {
                // [TODO: Log the event or throw exception or do both]
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        public Builder setSaveLocation (String absolutePath) {
            if (canModify()) {
                mManager.mSaveTo = Paths.get(absolutePath);
            }

            return this;
        }

        public Builder setMagnetUrl (String magnetUrl) {
            if (canModify()) {
                mManager.mMagnetUrl = magnetUrl;
            }

            return this;
        }

        public Builder setVlcPath (String absolutePath) {
            if (canModify()) {
                mManager.mVlcPath = Paths.get(absolutePath);
            }

            return this;
        }

        public Builder setInactivityResumeTimeout (int seconds) {
            if (canModify()) {
                mManager.mResumeAfterInactiveSeconds = seconds;
            }

            return this;
        }

        public Builder setFileIndex (int fileIndex) {
            if (canModify()) {
                mManager.mFileIndex = fileIndex;
            }

            return this;
        }

        public synchronized DownloadManager build () {
            isCompositionComplete = true;
            return mManager;
        }
    }

    public static DownloadManager buildFromState (String json) {
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonObject stateObject = parser.parse(json).getAsJsonObject();

        return new DownloadManagerImpl.Builder()
                .setMagnetUrl(stateObject.get(JsonKey.MAGNET_URL).getAsString())
                .setInactivityResumeTimeout(stateObject.get(JsonKey.RESUME_TIMEOUT).getAsInt())
                .setSaveLocation(stateObject.get(JsonKey.SAVE_LOCATION).getAsString())
                .setVlcPath(stateObject.get(JsonKey.VLC_PATH).getAsString())
                .setFileIndex(stateObject.get(JsonKey.FILE_INDEX).getAsInt())
                .build();
    }
}
```

I highly appreciate you taking the time to review my code.